# What transaction manager to use? (JPA, Spring)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I'm developing a web application based on JPA + Hibernate, Spring and Wicket. I was wondering what's the best way of implementing transactions in my code? What transaction manager should I use? Should it be `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`, or `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` or something else? I'd like to use Spring for managing my transactions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[nanda is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880563/what-transaction-manager-to-use-jpa-spring/3880573#3880573), you *can* only use JpaTransactionManager. The Transaction Manager abstraction we are talking about here is Spring's [PlatformTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) interface, and [JPATransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) is the only implementation of that interface that understands JPA.

You should read the chapter [Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction) from the Spring reference to better understand this topic.

Comment: +1 for your for completeness and +1 for nanda too to be fair :)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd If we can use JpaTransactionManager only then why there exists so many      other transacitonManagers in Spring and when they should be used?

Comment: @Erlan there is one transactionmanager implementation per persistence type: jdbc, hibernate, jpa, jdo

Comment: hmm. Now I see. Thanks

Comment: Why different persistence type（jdbc,hibernate,jpa...） rely on the same interface `PlatformTransactionManager`, but can only work with specific implementation?

Comment: @yuqizhang check out the [Javadoc page for PlatformTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) and look at the implementing classes.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd  Actually, I just read the source code of the `JPATransactionManager`, and `PlatformTransactionManager`,  found there are some type casting on method parameters. eg.`doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status)`,   which means they violate **"Dependency Inversion Principle"**  to get "flexibility", but this might confuse the user.

Comment: @yuqizhang probably true, but there's nothing I can do about that, I don't work for them :-)

Comment: a little late but as @Erlan asked about multiple Tx managers - where does weblogic Tx manager fit in ? if I have a spring , hibernate web application deployed on weblogic which transaction manager do I use if it involves only local transactions ?

Answer (score 18):

The org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager interface is the key abstraction in the Spring API providing essential methods for controlling transaction operations at run-time: begin, commit and rollback.

**PlatformTransactionManager** interface, its implementations

1. **JtaTransactionManager** -----> *JTA*
2. **DataSourceTransactionManager** -----> *JDBC*
3. **JpaTransactionManager** ------> *JPA*
4. **HibernateTransactionManager** ------> *Hibernate*

it depand on your requirment which moudle of spring your are using

Comment: This led me to the right place, thank you very much for this explanation. I had to use HibernateTransactionManager and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
```

My preference is to use this with annotation:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
```