# Which PlatformTransactionManager used for handling @Transactional in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to figure out an internal mechanism for handling @Transactional by Spring. As I understand transaction is handled by [PlatformTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html), which is abstract and has a lot of implementations (JDBC, JTA, JMS etc). But how Spring understand which exactly implementation of PlatformTransactionManager should be used?

For example I have method marked with @Transactional and inside this method I call jdbc, save to Redis and send message to JMS:

```
@Transactional
public void transactionMethod(){
  saveToSqlDatabase();
  saveToRedis();
  publishToTopic();
}
```

How Spring resolve which PlatformTransactionManager should be used?

Comment: Have you enabled transaction management? Usually, you define a transactionManager bean. It is described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html). For example with a single datasource (in old fashioned xml style...):

`<!-- Transaction manager -->
    <bean id="bpmnTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="bpmnDataSource"/>
    </bean>`

Comment: Can you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880563/what-transaction-manager-to-use-jpa-spring/45581887